# Backup SQLite Database File to SD Card

Tags: android

So I have seen plenty of examples of backing up a SQLite database file to the SD card and I have gotten this to work successfully on the android emulator in development, however it does not work as expected on the phone itself. Here is the strange part that I do no understand. Backing up the file does actually create the file on the SD card, however not all of the data that is present in the SQLite database used by the application is contained in the file that is backed up. Has anybody else run into this issue? Below is the code I am using to backup the file. The DB_PATH constant contains the value of /data/data/[package name]/databases/. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
try
{
                File dbFile = new File(DataBaseHelper.DB_PATH
                        + DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME);

                File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + DB_BACKUP_PATH);

                if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                    exportDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());

                file.createNewFile();
                FileUtil.copyFile(dbFile, file);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                BusinessLogic.errorHandler(e, ManageDataActivity.this);
                return false;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                BusinessLogic.errorHandler(e, ManageDataActivity.this);
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the database file without root privileges. That explains the behavior you're seeing.

Instead of copying the file itself, I would create a new database on the SD card and then try to copy all the data from the old database.